# Rewriting a Query String with two parameters in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, query-string

I usually don't use Apache, but here I kind of have to. I am having trouble rewriting an URL that takes two parameters over the query string and rewrites it.

The original URL is: `products.php?artist={artist_slug}&product={product_slug}` and I would like to rewrite it to `/artists/{artist_slug}/products/{product_slug}`.

The rewrite `RewriteRule ^artists/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /artist.php?artist=$1` works fine, but as soon as I extend from that forward to

`RewriteRule ^artists/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/products/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/ /products.php?artist=$1&product=$2`

it throws me a 404. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} artist=(.*)&product=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/artists/%1/products/%2? [R=301,L]
```

This grabs both of the query strings and then rewrites them to the following URL `http://example.com/artists/{artist_slug}/products/{product_slug}`. You'll see I've added a `?` onto the end of the Rewrite. That is to stop the `query_string` from appearing on the end of the URL.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this.